# Objective C: NSInvalidArgumentException on ApplicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Hi I'm trying to obscure the data in my app by adding an image in the app's screen when the *applicationDidEnterBackground*. However, when I tried to relaunch my app after being 'minimized' or background, I encountered and exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate window]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000258090'

Here is my source code:

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"BACKGROUND");
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    imageView.tag = 111;
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:imageView];

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"FOREGROUND");
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject viewWithTag:111];
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And also, why can't I test this to my Xcode's simulator? Any workaround on testing this obscuring of data in simulator?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your `AppDelegate` object have a `window` property?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yes Charles, it does have a window property.